# How do I tell LastPass to use (and update) a password for a group of sites?

Tags: lastpass

I know that, from a security perspective, using the same password for more than one website is a bad idea. However, I have a situation where I need to do that (the SE sites I have accounts on).

On *.stackexchange.com, I can use the same password entry across subdomains. However, for the older SE sites that have separate domains (SO, SU, SF, AU), I need to keep and update separate password entries in LastPass, which is annoying. Is there a way to group these sites, so that changing my password for stackexchange.com will automatically change it for SO, SU, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Open your LastPass Vault
- Go to **Account Settings → Equivalent Domains**.
- Add a comma-separated entry for all the domains you want to be considered the same.

Make sure the Domains you use are considered equivalent. For example:

> stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, mathoverflow.net, serverfault.com, stackapps.com, askubuntu.com

Apply the changes in the Settings, (requires Lastpass Master Password verification)

Comment: Here is the official documentation to this topic : https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/account-settings/equivalent-domains/